Using "the" with "return of someone/something"
I am completely baffled by the English language when it comes to the article "the" and "return of someone" or "return of something".
Here is a list of some movie titles I have found:
"The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King"
"Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi"
"Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker"
"Return of the Dragon"
"The Return of the King"
"The Return of the Pink Panther"
"Return to Oz"
"Return from Witch Mountain"
"Darkman II: The Return of Durant"
Could you please explain to me, when to use "the" with "return" and when to not?

There are lots of similar questions but basically grammatical rules don't apply in titles, which try to stand out and be unusual. You can ask about particular titles here or at movies and TV SE. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469114/zero-articles-in-movie-and-book-titles/ https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/444254/articles-in-movie-or-book-titles-noun-vs-adjective/ etc

It's down to the author's personal choice.

I’m voting to close this question because movie titles are not sentences / utterances in which syntax can usefully be analyzed.

I see nothing here that is special to movie titles, or to titles at all. Or indeed to collocations with return of. It’s vanilla-flavored English-language usage of the. What, exactly, confuses you so? What assumed patterns are violated by which of your examples?

@PaulTanenbaum I'm sorry but you would not start a sentence with return: a return, returns or the return.

Titles are a separate category so it's the author's choice. I would not close this since this is an important point for learners in this digital age.

Sorry, @Lambie, but who said anything about starting sentences? What have I missed?

@PaulTanenbaum I would specify, that's all. return in a title does not take the is the author doesn't want it to. Collocations is rather vague...return to Rome and die? [haha]

Return the book by Thursday or you’ll owe an overdue fee.

I am unable to find any in-depth info on using "the" in titles. Since English is the lingua franca, I would expect at least a book or two on this topic. Please, suggest some reputable resources. Thank you.

I don't think the word "return" has anything to do with it. After all, you're not suggesting that the word "the" later in the title should be omitted, like "Return of King." You're just noticing that sometimes some titles that start with common nouns precede them with "the" (like The Lord of the Rings) and sometimes they don't (like Lord of the Flies). In fact, it's common in casual and careless usage to use the opposite of whatever's in the official title ("I just read Lord of the Rings; I like it better than The Lord of the Flies."). There's no rhyme or reason to this; there doesn't need to be, since these aren't sentences, just fragments.

If it's a proper noun, (ie a name such as Witch Mountain) then you don't need an article.
Otherwise the phrase doesn't look right without one.  The implies that it is the same one that is returning (as in Return of the Pink Panther).
Otherwise you may say Return of a Pink Panther meaning any one (singular) Pink Panther.

But it's 'The Pink Panther' (proper name). And '[the] Joker' is a title, admittedly {definite article + name-which-employs-a-common-noun}, with 'Joker' always capitalised. Perversely, 'The Gambia' always has the article capitalised, while 'the United Kingdom' etc don't. Capitalisation rules fail if pushed.

I think this misses the question. The OP isn't asking about the "the" within the title, only at the beginning. All the ones that appear to be in the middle are actually the beginning of subtitles.
